# Google App Engine: DeadlineExceededError

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE app that does some heavy processing up front, then is able to do very little processing on subsequent user requests. However, when I deploy my app to the Google's servers, and try to do the heavy processing, I get a `DeadlineExceededError`. Is there any way around this?

**UPDATE**: What if I do something through `/remote_api`? That tolerated the 10 minutes it took to upload the data, so perhaps it's immune to the time limit on requests?

Answer (score 3):

Each script execution has a deadline of 30 seconds. `/remote_api` is no exception.

You may have a script running locally that takes 10 minutes to complete, however `/remote_api` is invoked once for every datastore RPC, so all this means is that each individual get, put, query, etc. finished before the deadline.

The bulk loader, task queues, and query cursors are all designed to make it easier to do heavy processing in small chunks. If you need assistance refactoring your processing code take advantage of these, please post some specific details about what you're trying to do.